# How to share resources between unit test and instrumentation test in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I'm following this post, http://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/, to share code, but how to share an asset?, like a fixture file?, I want to mock an api response, so I have a JSON file to do it, but I try this: https://gist.github.com/nebiros/91a68aaf6995fa635507

In Unit Test, this works:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("some_response.json");
```

but in Android Intrumentation Tests, it doesn't, where can I put those fixture files?.

Comment: Any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Nazneen I post the solution I found.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this way, to share fixture files from `test` to `androidTest`:

- Add your fixture files to the `resources` folder of your `test` one, here: `src/test/resources`.
- Add `test` resources folder to `androidTest`, `resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources']`, here's an example:

  ```
  android {
      sourceSets {
          String sharedTestJavaDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'

          test {
              java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
          }

          androidTest {
              java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
              resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources']
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Access fixture files from your `androidTest` env this way: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);`