# How to share JSON files between Android Test and Unit Tests in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I tried the suggestions given in the comments on this blog - http://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/

but the file cannot be read by the Android tests; unit tests work perfectly fine.

build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTestHelpers/java'
    String sharedTestAssetDir = 'src/sharedTestHelpers/assets'
    test {
        java.srcDir sharedTestDir
        assets.srcDir sharedTestAssetDir
    }
    androidTest {
        java.srcDir sharedTestDir
        assets.srcDir sharedTestAssetDir
    }
}
```

TestCreator class:

```
public class TestDataCreator {
  public static String readFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException    
  {
    return FileUtils.readFileToString(new    
    File("src/sharedTestHelpers/assets/" + fileName));
  }}
```

Project Structure:

[image: Project structure]

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instrumentation tests you should use Android APIs to read files from the assets folder.

If the file you want to read is in the `assets` folder of your test application (this is the case in your example) you have to use the `Context` of the test application. The test application context can be resolved trough `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`:

`// Opens an InputStream for the file src/sharedTestHelpers/assets/test.json
InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getAssets().open("test.json");`

If the file is in the assets folder of the app you need to use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`:

`// Opens an InputStream for the file src/main/assets/app.json
InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getAssets().open("app.json");`

Comment: I also followed the solution given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256623/how-to-share-resources-between-unit-test-and-instrumentation-test-in-android/37847307#37847307

Answer (score 1):

After lot more digging into this my observation

> Unit test can access this because it does not run in android .

**For Android test that is problem because**

1. Android Test in AVD/Device
2. If you look into your apk (by making as **testApk.zip** and extracting it) there is no folder like **/sharedTestHelpers/assets/** there is only **asset** folder
3. So for accessing asset folder you need **"Context"** for accessing context in test you can use

   **InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()**

Comment: Thank you. You are right. So I did follow the solution stated in the link above and it worked fine.